# Is it possible to launch boost thread on a non static member function from other memeber function

Tags: multithreading, boost, bind

like you probably know boost thread requires that memeber function that is fwd as argument must be static. There is a bind way to do it if it is not static, but I prefer the Object o; o.startThread() than
Object o;
boost::thread(boost::bind....) because it keeps the thread code inside the class(also exception handling). 
So for example can this be rewritten to work:

```
class sayHello
{
    string name;
public:
    sayHello(string name_):name(name_)
    {
    }
    void repeatHello()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            boost::this_thread::sleep(posix_time::seconds(3));
            cout<<"Hello "<<name<<endl;
        }
    }
    void infiniteRun()
    {
        boost::thread thr(repeatHello);//broken line
    }
};
```

P.S. for people wandering what is the "bind way" AFAIK it is this:

```
sayHello sh("world");
boost::thread thr(boost::bind(&sayHello::repeatHello,&sh));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes...

```
void infiniteRun()
{
    boost::thread thr(boost::bind(&sayHello::repeatHello,this));
}
```

Although doing it that way fraught with danger of memory leaks and access violations. When dealing with threads, I would highly recommend using smart pointers to keep things alive correctly.

Comment: I don't see how it's likely to have memory leaks at all, and possibly not access violations either.  If the first thing the destructor does is to stop the thread, what's the harm?

Comment: @John: Yes, if you code everything perfectly, then nothing will break. But not everything gets coded perfectly. That's why smart pointers are a good idea; because they ensure that the memory will continue to be around.

Comment: I know what smart pointers are for.  I just don't see what they would win you here.

Comment: @John: One of the most common mistakes when using threads and bind is having the bound arguments go out of scope, and hence destructed, and hence cause memory corruption and/or segmentation failures (if you are lucky). Using a smart pointer guards against that. People who try to wrap the Boost Thread code into the inheritance thread object paradigm are particular susceptible to this kind of mistake.

Comment: @GrafikRobot first sorry for the long delay(I read the answ immediately but couldnt test it at that time). Also can you explain a bit more on your last comment. I presume that you are talking about threads running on data that has been cleaned because object got out of scope(== destructed)?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Yes that's what I meant. If instead of passing in a raw pointer, in your case "this", you passed in a smart pointer it would prevent the object from getting destroyed as long as the thread is alive. It's not as easy to do in your case because of using "this". But it can be done by using an enabled_shared_from_this utility, for example.